# How to exclude year from date?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to take a year out of today's date to be able to make some simple calculations with age. Something like if I would like to know in what year somebody gonna be 100 years old if I know their age. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: I tried things like that:

'date.today()
destination = date.year - age'

and something in this kind

Comment: Do you mean "exclude" or "extract"?  It seems that you are asking the exact opposite of what the question title says.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to take a year from current date:

```
  import datetime
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot, I'm kinda new and don't get many things yet, even documentation is sometimes hard for me to understand.